# get the struts.xml action name in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have struts.xml like

```
<action name="actionName" class=myClass" method="myMethod"> 
            <result name="success" >/WEB-INF/jsp/fold/myJsp.jsp</result>    
            <result name="failure" >/WEB-INF/jsp/fold/myresult.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

Based on success or failure corresponding pages will be displayed. I want to get the action name in my jsp in case of failure.

Is it possible to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the name of the action thats being executed from inside the action, in your action execute method try something like:

```
 String actionName = ActionContext.getContext().getName();
```

Next, create a member variable to store this action name in action class (ex: `actionName`)

```
private actionName;
//set and get method
```

Last, use property tag to display action name in failure page called `myresult.jsp`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:if test="#context['struts.actionMapping'].name=='actionName'">
    <script>
     alert("here I go");
 </script>
  </s:if>
```

This works finally.